# Does Windows 8 ARM, A.K.A. "Windows RT" have the Winapi (win32) available for third party developers?

Tags: winapi, api, arm, windows-8

Windows 8 for ARM, also known as Windows RT, does it have the equivalent of the Win32 API?

(I *don't* mean if it can run Win32 x86 code, but if it has the Win32 API *available* to third party developers.)

Comment: I'll doubt Microsoft will ditch support for millions of millions of programs by obseleting WIN32. If they did, it would be big news indeed.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, I would think so too. But no one seems to come forward with a clean answer - IT'S LIKE THIS, HERE IS THE LINK. :-)

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant There hasn't been anything official said on Win8/ARM outside of Metro apps (where basically you can expect the same API surface on all platforms, which includes a certain subset of Win32). Hence why there's no link.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, yet they did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  Or rather, yes, but not as we knew ye, Win32. A small subset of the Win32 is available for WinRT apps to use, and WinRT apps are the only thing which gets to run on Windows RT. ("Windows 8 for ARM.")

Third party app developers can access but a fraction of the classic Win32 API.

Comment: And as a comment, I must say it looks like this: http://www.wired.com/business/2009/12/microsoft-eu-browser/  could very well happen again, but for Window RT this time.

Comment: A minor point: you really shouldn't quote wikipedia.  If you get something from there, just quote their source rather than the wiki itself.

Comment: Wikipedia is not an original source and will have more errors than the original.

Comment: Can I have some more votes for my answer people, this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, the ARM version will support the same APIs as x86 and x64 builds, possibly with some slight differences in architecture-specific stuff like exception handling.

For example, here's the list of APIs that the ARM version of msvcrt110.dll imports from kernel32:

```
Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 x86 tools.
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 10.00.40219.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file arm_msvcr110d_win8.pe

File Type: DLL

  Section contains the following imports:

    KERNEL32.dll
              100E4000 Import Address Table
              1012DA80 Import Name Table
                     0 time date stamp
                     0 Index of first forwarder reference

                  108 DecodePointer
                  12E EncodePointer
                  498 RtlPcToFileHeader
                  425 RaiseException
                  269 GetModuleFileNameA
                  26A GetModuleFileNameW
                  1AA FreeEnvironmentStringsW
                  26D GetModuleHandleExW
                  2A1 GetProcAddress
                  160 ExitProcess
                  3C7 MultiByteToWideChar
                  258 GetLastError
                  26E GetModuleHandleW
                  2C4 GetStdHandle
                  5C1 WriteFile
                  1D3 GetCommandLineA
                  1D4 GetCommandLineW
                  19D FlsGetValue
                  19E FlsSetValue
                  21A GetCurrentThreadId
                  [...]
                  4B1 SetConsoleCtrlHandler
                  361 IsDebuggerPresent
                  2F7 GetTickCount64
                  3F0 OutputDebugStringA
                  38C LCMapStringA
                  232 GetEnvironmentVariableA
                  233 GetEnvironmentVariableW
                  36E IsValidLocaleName
                  38D LCMapStringEx
                  339 HeapReAlloc
                  33B HeapSize
                  338 HeapQueryInformation
```

As you can see, all are standard Win32 stuff.

See also http://getwired.com/2011/09/20/win32-the-reports-of-my-death-are-greatly-exaggerated/

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I'm getting tired of being shouted down whenever this topic arises.

Comment: Technically, your list only shows that *some* Win32 API functions are available on ARM, not that the *full* Win32 API is.

Comment: Hey, your colleague Steven Sinofsky seems to differ: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/02/09/building-windows-for-the-arm-processor-architecture.aspx

Comment: And also @ScottWhitlock http://stackoverflow.com/a/10544190/193892 says that Windows 8 ARM will not give developers access to Win32 API.

Comment: Now we have the answer. Only Microsoft has access to the Win32 API on Windows RT.

Comment: "the ARM version will support the same APIs as x86 and x64 builds" - sorry, but that is just plain *false*. For Microsoft developers, yes, for everybody else, no. (As Firefox has noted, IE has an unfair API advantage on Windows RT.)

Answer (score 3):

As Igor Skochinsky pointed out, Windows RT has (almost) the same Win32 APIs as Windows for x86. If you write a "Metro" app using C++ and WinRT, you should be able to call these functions as you like. However, you can't get such an app into the Windows Store, as it will very likely fail the automated tests. You can only run it under a "developer license", which is a special development mode that allows you to sideload apps onto your device. (Disclaimer: This is based upon my experiments with Windows 8 for x86, and documentation I've read. I haven't tried this on an actual Surface RT. There might be additional blocks in place that prevent your app from running.)

Also, you can't run your own Desktop apps on Windows RT, as Windows checks the signature of the executable and only runs it if it is signed by Microsoft. (There will probably be way around this, either by Jailbraking, or by self-signing your executables. I've opened [a question on that topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13455035/running-win32-apps-compiled-for-arm-on-windows-rt), btw.)

Comment: Ok, I didn't say it in the question, but I meant if the API is available and will also pass application store tests. But interesting info nonetheless so +1