# Running Win32 apps compiled for ARM on Windows RT

Tags: windows-8, arm

Say I have a desktop program that uses the Win32 API, but is compiled for the ARM architecture. How do I get it to run on Windows RT (the restricted version of Windows 8 for ARM tablets)? Windows RT refuses to run such apps without a Microsoft signature.

I know there is no official way to do it, but say it is for an in-house deployment, or just for testing purposes. What are my options?

(See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8259020/143091) for the availability of Win32 API on Windows RT (not neccessarily for Metro apps, but present on the system), and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12347035/143091) for how to compile Win32 programs for ARM using VS2012.)

Comment: We probably aren't going to get an answer for this unless we can find someone that works for an OEM with an appropriate license.  That or we have to wait for someone to \*ahem\* bypass the current signature restrictions.  Then again, perhaps that's the answer.

Comment: There is some information floating around on the net on how to do it, but it's all unverified, and I don't have a Surface tablet to test it. Apparently, there are some directories from which Windows allows unsigned exes to start. There are also supposed to be registry keys that allow you to whitelist applications. Also it could be possible to self-sign executables, use "developer licenses" a.k.a. sideloading permissions, or to get some kind of large-vendor-inhouse-use-permission from MS. A last resort would be to patch system files. This question is mainly to separate the wheat from the chaff.

Comment: Your current options are none. Having quitted this out of the way, perhaps some jailbreaking process may give you that option, but you must wait a while for it to happen (if at all).

Comment: For starters, one could see if the techniques in this post work: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=33069395&postcount=10

Answer (score 6):

Now you can run any app/exe on Windows RT : http://surfsec.wordpress.com/2013/01/06/circumventing-windows-rts-code-integrity-mechanism/

Comment: Impressive, nice find. It's interesting how Windows RT is a perfect port of Windows 8, which was only restricted after the fact.

Answer (score 4):

please see this thread,and you can run you exe without a Microsoft signature by CreateProcessA
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1944675

Answer (score 2):

And now there is actually a "jailbreak"-like script:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2092158

> **Usage:**
>   Boot your RT device and log in, allow it to sit on the desktop for about a minute.
>   Run runExploit.bat, wait for it to do it's thing (shouldn't be more than 20 seconds or so)
>  
>   Press Volume Down
>  
>   Wait for runExploit.bat to finish, answer any prompts it gives. They should all be fairly self-explanatory.

It might crash while running the script, and it has to be done after every reboot. Also, I haven't tried it myself. In the post there is a link to a list of recompiled software that might be useful.