# Can I run an Windows 2003 SDK app on a Surface RT?

Tags: c++, windows-rt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Running Win32 apps compiled for ARM on Windows RT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13455035/running-win32-apps-compiled-for-arm-on-windows-rt)

I have a Windows app that I compile via Codewarrior and Windows 2003 SDK. It has worked great for me. I currently use Windows XP.

Can I somehow copy it to my Surface RT and run it?

Do I need to upgrade to Windows 8 and move to VC++ 2012?

EDIT: So i think I am seeing that it wont work without Windows 8 and VC++ for Surface RT as it is ARM based.

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to recompile it for the new processor.

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to recompile it for ARM processor.
2. You must sign your app by Microsoft!

Unfortunately, Microsoft only supports metro-style app for Windows RT and don't sign your app.
Windows desktop app not supported in Windows RT.

But you can use some method to bypass signature check:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1944675